# Parsing android resources from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am facing some problems with parsing a XML-file for my Android App.

I need some layout ids and color ids from my XML file. I have no problems in reading string values but I dont know how to convert the XML layout reference to a layout id? Thanks for your help!!

My XML file looks like that:

```
<program
    name="ProgramName"
    color="@color/white"
    prefLayoutId="@layout/pref" />
```

My parsing code works like that. The parsing of color/layout does not work:

```
XmlPullParser xmlParser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.programlist);

int event = xmlParser.getEventType();
while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    String name = xmlParser.getName();

    switch (event) {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG: {
            break;
        }
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG: {
            if(name.equals("program")) {
                ProgramInfo pi = new ProgramInfo();

                pi.name = xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");

                // HERE I need something like COLOR.Black;
                pi.color = Integer.valueOf(xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null, "color"));

                // HERE I need something like R.layout.pref
                pi.pref = Integer.valueOf(xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null, "prefLayoutId"));

                result.add(pi);
         }
         break;
     }
}

event = xmlParser.next();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
XmlResourceParser xmlParser = resources.getXml(R.xml.programlist);

...

int resourceId = xmlParser.getAttributeResourceValue(null, "color", 0);
pi.color = (resorceId == 0) ? SOME_DEFAULT_COLOR : resources.getColor(resourceId);
pi.pref = xmlParser.getAttributeResourceValue(null, "prefLayoutId", 0);
```

[*getAttributeResourceValue*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html#getAttributeResourceValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) will return a referenced resource id, stored in corresponding value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It says "Cannot resolve getAttributeResourceValue(..)". What's wrong?

Comment: replace xmlParser variable type from XmlPullParser to XmlResourceParser

Comment: Well, then there is the problem that I cannot get the AttributeValue "name". Is better to use an AttributeSet Xml.asAttributeSet(xmlParser)? But both ways, your code an the use of AttributeSet.getAttributeResourceValue do not have the same behaviour like R.layout.pref. But where is the difference.

Comment: XmlResourceParser is the super interface for XmlPullParser. So, you can use getAttributeValue as well, in either way.XmlResourceParser  also implements AttributeSet, so you not need to convert it in some additional way. On result of getAttributeResourceValue is a id of resource, or zero (the third parameter), if resource is not found. So, if found, it should be the same as if you access R.layout.pref directly

Comment: One possible issue I just have noted: you parsing values in XmlPullParser.END_TAG, but it should be done in XmlPullParser.START_TAG. Try to move your code there

Comment: Thank you for your help. After your corrections it works the way I want it to. Thank you again!